# Same Keystore and package name

Tags: android, apk, keystore

For some technical reasons, I am recreating the app with the same package name in another computer.

Can I still use the same old keystore here without any problem ?
Will I be able to publish in google play with this setup ?

Comment: yes of course you can

Comment: No reason to downvote @ whoever did that....

Comment: Did you ultimately go through with that? Please tell me if it ultimately worked coz Im going to do the same. Thanks in advance!

Comment: yes it works. I tried it